# In prototype.js in magento on line 1931 when we see it on firebug

Tags: prototypejs, firebug, magento-1.7

I am facing `element.style.display = 'none';` this error in prototype.js  in line 1931 in magento 1.7

someone please shortout this problem as soon as problems.

Comment: Yes, I got this same error. I debugged it by closing div, I found that error was gone when I closed header div and after deep digging, it was form.mini.phtml in catelogsearch folder, the JavaScript in this page using a div which was deleted by me so that made element null

Answer (score 0):

That line number is referring to the `hide()` method. However I think you are using an older version of PrototypeJS as this line is at a different line number in the current version (1.7.1).

Regardless most likely you are trying to run the `hide()` method on an element that does not exist in your current DOM.

For Instance

```
$('missingid').hide();
//There is no element on the page with the id "missingid" so this will fail
```

Double check the id you are trying to hide as well as check the version of PrototypeJS that you have loaded.